# Yii2 - Registering asset with twig

Tags: twig, assets, yii2

I'm using yii2 with twig and trying to use any assets classes within my templates. I was trying my own classes, or the ones provided with yii2, but none of them work and none of them even raise any error. 
Below my layolut declaration:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Below declaration doesn't work - try to fix it later -->
    {{ use ('/frontend/assets/AppAsset' )}}
    {{ register_app_asset() }}
    <html lang="{{app.language}}">
   <head>
    <meta charset="{{app.charset}}"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Other head stuff -->
    {{ html.csrfMetaTags()|raw }}
    <title>
      {{html.encode(this.title)}}
    </title>
    {{this.head()}}
   </head>
```

is doing nothing _ I'm not getting scripts registered nor any error.
Thanks for help

Comment: Do you use twig for layout ? Show us header template.

Comment: Added start of my layout file where I'm registering AppAsset

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, but register app asset normally uses $this in PHP, what would be the equivalent in twig - this perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, and this works for me:

```
{{ use('frontend/assets/AppAsset')}}
{{ register_app_asset() }}
```

Judging from your code, the only difference I can see is that you prepend the use function argument with a slash.

Comment: It does look like we're on our own when using (or trying to use) Twig with Yii2. It doesn't seem to be that well supported.

Comment: For the time being I'm just declaring everything manually which is pity, but don't have to much time investigating this thing. I've tried your way Today and doesn't seem to work unfortunately.